# Why doesnt my Spring Security authentication work?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, restful-authentication

I have the following configuration placed in `/src/main/java/com/dog/bootstrap`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and I am loading it as follows:

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.scan("com.dog.bootstrap");

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
            container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    Set<String> mappingConflicts = dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    if (!mappingConflicts.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("'dispatcher' could not be mapped to '/' due " +
                "to an existing mapping.");
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class DogController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/dog"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getSource(@PathVariable("domain") String domain) throws Exception {
        return "dogs";
    }
}
```

When I startup my app, I do see `hello` being printed, so `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` is being called. However, none of my endpoints are requiring me to enter a login page. When I go to `localhost:8080/dog` it outputs `dogs` without asking me to authenticate myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually including the filter chain, [as described in the last step of this guide](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/). Try adding this default initializer, which maps to `/*`:

```
@Component public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```